# Searching for List of Substrings for a String in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of filenames:

```
 List<string> FileList = new List<string>();
 FileList.Add("c:\fn1.rpt");
 FileList.Add("c:\fn2wxy.txt");
 FileList.Add("c:\fn3.pdf");
```

I have a list of candidates for deletion:

```
List<string> DeleleList = new List<string>();
DeleteList.Add("fn2")
```

I have a loop that loops through the file names and I am looking for the correct expression that basically figures out if the file name fragment in the DeleteList matches the current file.  In this case, we would delete c:\fn2.txt only.  I can iterate the list but it seems as though there must be a Lambda expression somewhere beyond my IQ.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the file name in a variable called `fileName`, then:

- if you want an exact match, then just use `Contains`:

`if (DeleteList.Contains(fileName))`

- if you want a partial match

`if (DeleteList.Any(fileToDelete => fileToDelete.Contains(fileName)))`

Instead of `Contains` you can also use `StartsWith` or `EndsWith`.

**Edit**: I'm assuming your complete code should look like this:

```
foreach (filename in FileList)
{
   if (DeleteList.Any(fileToDelete => fileToDelete.Contains(fileName)))
   {
       // delete file
   }
}
```

Though, as others have mentioned, matching on strings like this is not necessarely the best approach. Also, it would probably more intuitive to create a list of files to delete (matching existing files) and iterate through that as a final step and delete the files; like so:

```
var filesToDelete = FileList.Where(f => DeleteList.Any(df => df.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f), StringComparer.OrginalIgnoreCase)));
foreach (var filePath in filesToDelete)
{
    //delete file
}
```

Comment: I clarified my question.  I'm not able to get your answer to work so maybe with my additional comments, I could do it.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working after the update to my answer? & what exactly wasn't working with the original answer?

Comment: Sorry it has taken me so long to get back to you.  Originally, it wasn't finding the file fragments.  I will test this out this weekend.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You should not search substrings but use [`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example with LINQ (keep only those names which don't appear in the `DeleteList`):

```
fileNames = fileNames
  .Where(n => !DeleteList.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(n)))
  .ToList()
```

If you want to ignore the case, so treat `fn2` and `FN2` equal, use:

```
.Where(n => !DeleteList.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(n), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: In case the OP need it, one can make it case insensitive using `.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(n), StringComparer.OrginalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: Now this is a way bigger thought than I originally had but why the heck not?  Seriously -- I wasn't going for the whole directory - just the array of file names.  I'll check it out.  I am looking for substrings -- kind of like wildcards.  Starts with FN2 -- could be FN2i928340983.xyz.